# How to connect attributes from list when Maya does not find those attributes?

Tags: maya, python

What I am looking to do is batch connect attributes from object A to object B. Just the transform attributes, so, I did this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

sel = mc.ls(sl=True)

mc.connectAttr(sel[0]+'.t', sel[1]+'.t')
mc.connectAttr(sel[0]+'.r', sel[1]+'.r')
mc.connectAttr(sel[0]+'.s', sel[1]+'.s')
```

And then I thought it would be more clever if I created a list containing (`translate`, `rotate` and `scale`) and just iterate over that list instead of specifying `".t"`, `".r"` and `".s"`.

So I did this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

sel = mc.ls(sl=True)
attributes = ['.t', '.r', '.s']

for attr in attributes :
    mc.connectAttr(sel[0].attr, sel[1].attr)
```

...to which the console says

```
# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 7: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'attr' #
```

I did some searching, but it didn’t help me understand. Can someone explain why this is happening, and how I can achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 2):

Your last line has to be:

```
mc.connectAttr(sel[0]+attr, sel[1]+attr)
```

You are using `.` as if it were the string concatenation error in Python, while `+` is.

Instead `.` is the attribute operator, which explains your error¹. When Python tries to interpret `sel[0].attr`, it first notes that `sel[0]` is a `unicode` object and then tries to get the attribute `attr` from that object. This attribute has nothing to do with the `attr` from your loop and in particular doesn’t exist. Hence the error message you got.

---

¹ Every object in Python has some attributes, which you can access with that syntax and which depend on the type object. To get familiar with this try:

```
a = 42
print(a.numerator)
print(a.denominator)

print(a.wrzlprmft)
# Raises AttributeError. This is what happened to you.

print(denominator)
# Raises NameError.
# This demonstrates that denominator is only defined as an attribute of a.
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked.

To be honest though I don't really understand why it worked... first why has attr nothing to do with attr from my loop ? I specified it by name in the loop header ?

And then unsure about another thing : in Maya attributes accessed by name need to have that dot before their name (cf my first example), so why don't they when they are accessed through a variable ?

Thanks again,

Hadrien

Comment: Oh I get the second point : the dots are already contained in the list items !

So what was I really calling when I wrote ".attr" ? This is still super unclear to me ?

Comment: @Hadriscus: See my edit. — *So what was I really calling when I wrote ".attr" ?* – Something that doesn’t exist; hence the error.

Comment: @Hadriscus "XYZ" is a string. O.XYZ is a attribite of O. `attributes = ['.t', '.r', '.s']` attributes is list of strings. Thus attr is a string (that confusingly is called an attribute, but thats because its attribute of a node not a python object!). Your example is building strings. Thus your for loop needs to build strings.